# Office-addin Authentication

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

I'm currently using Auth0 authentication in my add-in. Now, I want to allow users to use my add-in without authentication. 
**Are there any protocols that I need to follow to remove authentication, any documentation link?**

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit, you're using Auth0 to auth your users with what exactly? Do you have your own account system setup? Why can't you just remove auth0?

Comment: We have same question as Mavi. Why are you using Auth0 authentication library? Can you remove it if it is unused?

Comment: Yes, I've an account system setup. Here, when I remove the auth0, do I have to send my add-in again for approval to Microsoft team?

Comment: There is no need to re-submit to the Microsoft team if there's no change in the Manifest file. Code change doesn't require resubmission.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT if the auth removal indicates moving from a paid (accounted) to free (unaccounted) doesn't that require a re-submission?

Comment: @MaviDomates Do you mean paid add-in to free add-in? Starting July 29th, 2019, we no longer accept new paid add-ins to Microsoft AppSource.